# How to do/simulate an empty char in a ternary expression

Tags: c, conditional-operator

I'm trying to format a string like this:

```
printf("%d%c", buffer[i], i == num_ints-1? '': ',');
```

So that the numbers print like this:

```
123,929,345
```

Yet doing `''` is invalid. Is it possible to simulate a 'nothing-char' or just not do anything in the ternary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have an empty char, but you can have empty strings. So use `%s`.

```
printf("%d%s", buffer[i], i == num_ints-1? "": ",");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should also be able to use the null character `'\0'` here.

```
printf("%d%c", buffer[i], i == num_ints-1? '\0': ',');
```